# django - custom filter not working properly

Tags: python, django, django-custom-tags

I am writing a custom filter which should hightlight the char or chars with `<strong>` if this char or chars are contained in the given text.

this is my custom filter:

```
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
def highlight(text, sterm, autoescape=None):
   if autoescape:
       esc = conditional_escape
   else:
       esc = lambda x: x
   result = text.replace(esc(sterm),'<strong>'+esc(sterm)+'</strong>')
   return mark_safe(result)
```

and in template I `{% load %}`ed and used in this way:

```
{{search_result_text|highlight:searchterm}}
```

The problem is it is highlighting all text which comes after the matched term:

[image]

as you see, the first block is what is happening right now. I want to achieve the second block. I searched for `level`

What is wrong with my code?

**EDIT**: Sorry, it is my typo. I didnot close `<strong>` properly, now it is working like a charm! :). I leave this here so other can make use of it.

Comment: Just post your solution as an answer and accept it then :)

Comment: @alecxe hey Alex, just a quick question: after applying my filter, i wanted to make ``capfirst`` like this ``{{var|highlight:term|capfirst}}`` but ``capfirst`` is failing, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Sure, you can try to use [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filter) to chain the filters, or just apply `capfirst` before the `highlight` :)

Comment: @alecxe thanks, but i applied ``capfirst`` first and my filter second, no success. i think i need to go for filter.

Comment: Have you tried this `{{var|capfirst|highlight:term}}`?

Comment: @alecxe, yes, but no success. i even did ``text.capitalize()`` before ``text.replace()`` inside function. not a single sign of success! :)

Comment: Ok, what if you make a separate question out of it? Though, I wonder why `capfirst` doesn't work in your case. It's does one exact thing and it's simple. Also, does it work without `highlight:term`: `{{var|capfirst}}`?

Comment: @alecxe yeah alone it is working without my filter. i think, i will ask separate question on it, because i have the feeling that my filter  returning something bad which cannot be taken by ``safe``. weird.. but thanks man, see ya on da way in sof ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my typo: I didnot close `<strong>` properly inside my filter function.

Now it is working like a charm!